# Why cant receive ether on my proxy contract?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat, openzeppelin

I use proxy implementation from hardhat. This is the smart contract code.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import "hardhat-deploy/solc_0.8/proxy/Proxied.sol";

contract PoolContract is Initializable, Proxied, AccessControl {
    receive() external payable {}
    fallback() external payable {}
}
```

When trying to send ether to this contract, the transaction revert with "ETHER_REJECTED"

When I try to use OpenZeppelin UUPS, it works, but I need to use only hardhat implementation

Comment: Tested in Remix VM: This contract is able to receive funds. Based on the error message, the issue is possibly caused on the sender (likely a contract sender, not EOA).